# Upgrade 16.04 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade

I would like to move to 18.04 LTS, can someone clarify me how to please?
16.04 installed
Thanx

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Firstly upgrade to latest of your current with`sudo apt update` to update repository lists of software then `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to install updated software. Finally `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade to the next release.  Reboot when required

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is run command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```